# C++ Types Impossible to Name

Tags: c++, templates, types, c++11, decltype

While reading [Wikipedia's page on decltype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype), I was curious about the statement,

> Its [decltype's] primary intended use is in generic
>   programming, where it is often
>   difficult, **or even impossible**, to name
>   types that depend on template
>   parameters.

While I can understand the *difficulty* part of that statement, what is an example where there is a need to name a type that cannot be named under C++03?

**EDIT**: My point is that since everything in C++ has a declaration of types.  Why would there ever be a case where it is impossible to name a type?  Furthermore, aren't trait classes designed to yield type informations?  Could trait classes be an alternative to `decltype`?

Comment: The statement about impossible-to-name types was taken from [n1478](http://std.dkuug.dk/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1478.pdf)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The wikipedia page you link has a perfect example:

```
int& foo(int& i);
float foo(float& f);

template <class T> auto transparent_forwarder(T& t) −> decltype(foo(t)) {
  return foo(t);
}
```

Note that `foo(int&)` returns `int&` (a reference type) while `foo(float&)` returns `float` (a nonreference type). Without `decltype`, it's impossible within the template to specify a type which represents "the return type of the function `foo` which takes an argument `t` of type `T`".

In this example, it's not a *particular* concrete type which is impossible to express -- either `int&` or `float` are individually expressible -- but a higher level generic class of types.

EDIT: and to answer your comment to another answer, this example is inexpressible in C++03. You cannot have a function template which will wrap any function `T1 foo(T2)` and match both argument and return type of the wrapped function.

Comment: Could trait classes be used to solve this problem?  In your example, the return type of `transparent_forwarder` could be `functor_traits<T>::return_type`.

Comment: @Kirakun: that breaks DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) and reduces maintainability. If you want to change `int foo(float)` to `float foo(float)`, you had better remember to change `functor_traits` as well. IOW, yes, you can do it, but it's kludgy and crying for a feature to make it nicer.

Comment: Should be `(T&& t)` and `return foo(std::forward<T>(t));` if the function name is to be truthful.

Comment: @GMan: I don't understand. can you edit my answer to show what you mean? (I can make it CW if you like).

Comment: @Philip: No, don't CW it. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward/3582313#3582313 and let me know if you have any questions after. It doesn't matter for your specific case, but in general "forward", "forwarder", or "forwarding" implies the use of `std::forward`.

Comment: The example was taken from [n1705](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1705.pdf) (a 2004 paper). If I'm not mistaken, the paper is completely independent of other (proposed) C++0x features, such as rvalue references.

Answer (score 11):

There are types in C++0x (and in C++03, but less often) that cannot be named explicitly, such as the type `decltype(f)` after the declaration `auto f = [](int x) -> int {return x;};`.  You would need to `typedef` that `decltype` result to something to get a name at all.  Traits classes can be used for determining return types, but they are messy, and the user needs to duplicate all of their function overloads with traits class overloads; that is difficult to do correctly for cases such as functions applying (through implicit conversion of pointers) to all subclasses of a given base class.

Comment: So, are these "impossible" types only occur in C++0x but not in C++03?

Comment: @Kirakun: Exactly, just like `decltype`.

Comment: @Kirakun: well, not really, there *are* anonymous types in C++03, but they are much less frequent.

Comment: Lambda's cannot appear as an unevaluated expression.

Comment: @GMan: I fixed it to have a separate variable for the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, the type if it exist is known by the compiler, otherwise it wouldn't exist. However, it is not always readily or even accessible to the programmer in C++03.

[N1607](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1607.pdf) mention the following in its conclusion:

> In C++2003, it is **not possible** to
>   express the return type of a function
>   template **in all cases**. Furthermore,
>   expressions involving calls to
>   function templates commonly have very
>   complicated types, which are
>   practically impossible to write by
>   hand

The question is how do we access this type as a programmer. This is not always a trivial process, often impracticable.  It is increasingly complex when you have an expression for which you desire to know the result type. You would have to break it into pieces in order to figure the result types. It is not possible to simplify this process using templates (not without evaluating the expression anyhow). Breaking the expression will be error-prone, tedious and a nightmare to maintain. Think of this code:

```
x.g()[b.a(e)]->f();
```

With C++98/TR1, it is often infeasible to name types that depend on template parameters. Traits offers us so much information, but eventually decltype is a much cleaner solution to many problems. A lot of the information available to you when meta programming is only available because libraries, such as boost or loki, use several tricks hidden in the dark corners of the C++98 language.

Of course this is irrelevant to your question but I believe that it is worthy to mention that C++98 compilers already have mechanics to know these types. This is exactly what sizeof offers, except that it returns you a size. decltype reuse some of this functionality  and solves these problems with greater elegance.

As for a different (academic) example:

```
struct Foo
{
    struct
    {
        int x;
    } bar;
};

template<typename T>
void
f(const T& t)
{
    // C++03, How can I name the type of T::bar ?

    // C++0x
    // decltype(t.bar) cpy;
    // Do stuff with our local cpy
}

int
main()
{
    f(Foo());
}
```